# How to search files specific XML code pattern

Tags: python, regex, xml, parsing

I have to search for files (around 2000) for the following string patern, which I do using **grep** as follows:

`grep -irn ".acu" .`

The response would be 100s of lines with the following pattern:

```
<cf_query Query="DSSQuery" Program="qdss.acu" xxx>
```

Then I will have check whether the line found (above), is surrounded by the xml tags as follows (xxx is irrelevant)

```
<cfif IsDefined("REQUEST.<STRING>") xxx>
    <cfmodule 
        template="xxx" 
        Service="xxx" 
        Action="xxx" 
        QueryString="xxx"
        ReturnVariable="xxx">
<cfelse>
    <cf_query Query="DSSQuery" Program="qdss.acu" xxx>
</cfif>
```

If YES then I extract the `<STRING>` and then I do something with the string.

I am familiar with Lex-Yacc, and also looked into [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) but seems like an overkill. Can I get a pointer where to start with this, and any efficient way to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookaround tags eg. https://regex101.com/r/wF3nD3/2

```
(?s)(?<= ReturnVariable="xxx">\n<cfelse>\n)PATTERN(?=\n</cfif>)
```

where

- (?s) is for single line mode
- (?<= ....) lookbehind pattern
- (?= .....) lookahead pattern

Comment: Well this didn't work for most of the files as the code varies & after much of research I found that a `Regular Expression` cannot be created for CFML as it's not `Regular Language`.